# Are there infinitely many prime numbers in the Look-and-say sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Question:

> Are there infinitely many prime numbers in the [Look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)?

In the sequence, I found that $11$, $312211$ and $13112221$ are prime numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Not an answer.*

I generated the first $50$ terms of the sequence; it does not take much time.  The prime search is another story. Among the first $38$ (above, my computer gave up), as prime numbers, I only found the second  and the two you reported.

Congratulations.

Comment: any prime needs certain properties, one of which is the digits that are non zero mod 3, can only exceed the other type of digits non zero mod 3 by a quantity that are 1 or 2 mod 3.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee. I am very bad in number theory, prime numbers (plus many other areas); so, I feel vry dumb when reading your comment. So, taking into account the manner these numbers are generated, do you have any idea about their primilarity ?

Comment: no, but if we can check how many 1's versus 2's there are we can limit which iterations we ultimately  check for primality.

Comment: So is this a hypothesis? And could I name it?

Comment: I should not conclude anything. This was just an observation based on the $38$ first terms. May be, looking at his comments,  Roddy MacPhee could help.